# for every positive integer $n$, find $n$ consecutive numbers which are not squarefree

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to show that for every positive integer $n$, I can find $n$ integers in a row whose prime factorization contains at least one prime twice.

I checked the cases $n=2$ $(8,9)$ and $n=3$ $(48,49,50)$ but I don't have an idea how to find a general proof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p_0,p_1,\dots, p_{n-1}$  be distinct primes.  Consider the system of congruences
$$x\equiv -i \pmod{p_i^2}$$
($i=0,1,2,\dots, n-1$).

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, this system has a solution $a$. Note that $a$ is divisible by $p_0^2$, $a+1$ is divisible by $p_1^2$,  and so on.

Comment: You are welcome. I had started typing $p_0$ to $p_{n-1}$ for the primes, changed my mind but did not change all the indices. Corrected.  And it is $x\equiv -(i-1)$.

Comment: Changed the indexing back to the one I really wanted. It is prettier to start counting at $0$.

Comment: Great, I think everything is clear now. Thanks again!